# Where to import mongo-2.10.1 jar in REST Web Server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mongodb, rest

I am implementing a rest web service for android web service without mongodb works well.
But when I use mongo classes I get an error like this:

```
Jan 15, 2014 8:39:29 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
```

I think eclipse can not access the mongo jar files. i placed the jar like this:
[image]
 I think I am putting  mongo-2.10.1 jar file to wrong place. But I am not sure. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JEE Web Server (Tomcat 7 in this case) dependent jars are usually placed in WEB-INF/lib (for runtime).